# export and import sqlite database problem android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have problem with implementation code for export and import (backup for users ) on my.

I tried the below code but I couldn't find the created folder and also copied database. the the purpose of the code is give the user this option to export his settings and save them somewhere accessible. and I want to have this ability if user remove the app the backup file remain on the phone or at least user should be able to copy it somewhere else or share it .
Could someone check my code and let me know what is the problem of it ?

```
public class UserBackupActivity extends BaseActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.addContentView(R.layout.activity_user_backup);

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(UserBackupActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(UserBackupActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(UserBackupActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 5);
        }
    } else {
        File mydir = new File(getExternalFilesDir("")+ "/mydir/");


        if (!mydir.exists()){
            mydir.mkdirs();

        }

        else
            Log.d("error", "dir. already exists");


        exportDB();
        // importDB();

    }
}


private void exportDB() {
    String DatabaseName = "user.db";
    File sd = getExternalFilesDir("");
    File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();



    FileChannel source = null;
    FileChannel destination = null;
    String currentDBPath = "/data/" +getPackageName()+ "/databases/" + DatabaseName;
    String backupDBPath = "/mydir/mydatabase";
    File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
    File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);



    try {
        source = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
        destination = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
        destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
        source.close();
        destination.close();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Your Database is Exported !!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

when I run the code I got "Your Database is Exported !!" message but I can not find the database file on emulator . also my target android Api is 31.

thanks .

Comment: "but I can not find the database file on emulator" -- where are you looking? "I want to have this ability if user remove the app the backup file remain on the phone" -- your code does not support that. You will need to use the Storage Access Framework (`ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` / `ActivityResultContracts.CreateDocument`) for that. In the context of Room, I cover this subject in [this chapter](https://commonsware.com/Room/pages/chap-backup-001.html) of [this free book](https://commonsware.com/Room).

Comment: Hi . Thanks for your response . It showed the location here.
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.test.app/files/mydir/mydatabase

but when I check with emulator after data folder there is nothing .